# Nginx Reverse Proxy to bridge pc not working

Tags: nginx

Trying to work out why my reverse proxy dont work.

I want to connect to 192.168.1.80 on port 443 on each site.

I have a vps server set up with apachie and nginx. I want to connect to multipul locations without having to open firewalls. So I have a bridge pc on each site with apchie and niginx also.

My vps has a config like this :

```
stream { 

#Site 1
    server { 
    listen 2323; 
    proxy_pass x.x.x.x:443;
     
} 

#Site 2
    server { 
    listen 2324; 
    proxy_pass x.x.x.x:443;
     
} 

}
```

x.x.x.x being the external IP of each site.

Then each bridge pc has this to receive the incoming connection is set up like this.

```
# Site 1
stream {
     upstream pos {
    server 192.168.1.80:443;
}
server {
        listen 0.0.0.0;443;
    proxy_pass pos;
  }
}
```

If I open port 443 to 192.168.1.80 it works, but i dont want to open ports for security reasons. As i want to use vps only with restricted IPs.